# Geometric series of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know that $$I+M+M^2+\cdots$$ is convergent iff $\rho(M)<1$.

And if it is convergent then it coverges to $(I-M)^{-1}$

**Doubts** If all entries of $M$ are positive then I feel that all entries of $(I-M)^{-1}$ should also be positive. But In actual this need not true. Please help me

Comment: What is the $\rho$?

Comment: @C.F.G It's a rather standard notation for the spectral radius of the matrix.

Comment: do you have a counterexample for this doubt?

Comment: @C.F.G yes I have you take  $M=\begin{bmatrix} 1/3 & 1/3 \\1/3 & 1/3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @AbsoluteWWork : In your counterexample $(I-M)^{-1}$ has only positive entries?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+inverse&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22MatrixInverse%22,+%22invmatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B2%2F3,-1%2F3%7D,%7B-1%2F3,2%2F3%7D%7D%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22matrix+inverse%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D

Comment: it is easy to find a matrix $A$ with positive entries such that $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists and has some negative entry, but none of these have radius $\rho(A)<1$

Comment: @Veridian Dynamics can you give me proof of this

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: @Veridian Dynamics, How it can be occur while all entries of each term of $I+M+M^2+\cdots$ are positive?

Comment: @C.F.G - It can occur because if $\rho(M) \ge 1$, then $I + M + M^2 + ...$ doesn't converge, and therefore it is not the inverse of $I - M$.